# XLPagerTabStrip: doesn't respect the status bar

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9, xlpagertabstrip

I'm having difficulty applying `XLPagerTabStrip`, it's not about the coding itself, but on your screen organization, a few days ago I've been researching but I just circled, used this framework before, I had no difficulties since the code in my application used the full screen, but with the launch of iPhone X had to change the view mode of the app and with that I could not make `XLPagerTabStrip` respect the constraints of the "safe area" as you can see in the image below

[image: img-pager]

I would like to know how to force this limit, since I've tried almost everything.

proper even making a new separate project just to test this problem has remained.

I figured that it was some error in my code then re-created but the problem remained.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.
I managed to make it work when I added a collection view inside my storyboard, assigned it to ButtonBarView class and connect it to VC's buttonBarView. That way I was able to set the size and other constraints and now it works like I want.

Refer to this post [How to implement Android-Like Tab Layouts in iOS using swift 3](https://medium.com/michaeladeyeri/how-to-implement-android-like-tab-layouts-in-ios-using-swift-3-578516c3aa9) to see the exact process.